# How To Make A Stiped-Grate Material

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, node-editor, geometry

So I'm currently making a First Order TIE Fighter and I need help making the TIE's texture on its wings. Specifically this texture...[image]

I'm not sure if I should somehow recreate the geometry of a grated-lines look, or use nodes to make simple bump texture. Can anyone give me a hand with some ideas?

Comment: Please use a descriptive title

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to explain the type of texture I'm requesting for but I'll try to fix it.

Comment: "*Tie Fighter texture*" would have sufficed

Comment: You may be able to tweak the Brick texture node to work to make it.

Answer (score -1):

I would do some manual loop cuts with Ctrl+R and then follow the instructions I wrote in this answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161417/how-to-render-surface-divisions-for-subsurface-modifier)