# How to render surface divisions for subsurface modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface, wireframe

I want to render the outline of faces as shown in the below image to show the divisions of panels. How to do this in Blender?
[image]

Comment: Haven't got time to write an answer, but look up Freestyle in Blender.

Answer (score 2):

If you want small gaps in the tiles you can use the edge split modifier and the solidify modifier. make sure you set the offset to +1 on the solidify mod.
[image: Example of inlaid wireframe]

Another thing you can try if you want the mesh lines to be extruded outwards,you can duplicate the object that you want to see the subdivisions on and use the wireframe modifier on it.
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

you could capture from the viewport with a flat white shading and the subdivision modifier "on cage" turned on, and then use the compositor to overlay it onto a regular render from the same camera.

[image]